# One Project, Multiple Git Repo Merge problems

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I'm working on a project that wishes to have the following workflow:

Team of developers do normal git workflows from an internal Gitlab repo, let's call this repo "Alpha"  At some point, we are happy with the state of the project, have done internal reviews and wish to push the new code to Github (repo "Beta").

Sounds simple enough, except we are all fairly new to git, and have tried several various ways without success.  In a fit of frustration, we clone Beta, blow away all the files except the .git dir copy in the files form repo Alpha (again except the .git dir), do a commit -a, push, declare success, and walk a way with a bad feeling that there has to be a better way.

So Here's a "log" of our latest effort to do it using "git":

Repo Alpha = internal git lab
Repo Beta  = external github project

```
~ $ mkdir work
~ $ cd work
~ $ # create the clone of Beta
~ $ git clone https://github.com/foo/xot.git
~ $ # create the clone of Alpha
~ $ git clone git@internal.foo.com:xot/XOT.git
~ $ ls
xot/       XOT/
~ $ # go work in the clone of Beta
~ $ cd xot
~/xot $ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
~/xot $ git remote add Internal ../XOT
~/xot $ git remote -v
Internal    ../XOT (fetch)
Internal    ../XOT (push)
origin    https://github.com/foo/xot.git (fetch)
origin    https://github.com/foo/xot.git (push)
~/xot $ git pull Internal master

<boom>
1000's of conflicts
```

Sure we could do "git mergetool" and die of old age as we say, "yes, delete that file," and "yes, take the internal repo's version" to each of the thousands of conflicts.

Here's a graph representation of what we are trying to do:

```
               commits
Repo Alpha     a12f -----> c676 -----> .... ----> d4a2

now we want to apply all the commits to repo Beta:

Repo Beta      a12f ----------------------------> d4a2
```

Casting about I saw reference (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge/2.14.2)  to "git pull -s theirs" as a possible automerge strategy.  Except that git errors out saying that theirs is not a valid strategy (i'm running git 2.14.2 on Ubuntu 14.04)

What are we missing here?  Is there a proper/better way to do this?

Comment: If it's the same project, you can just change the `origin` doing 
`git remote set-url origin https://github.com/foo/xot.git` .
this is a proper way to work with different repository with the same project and keeping the history but you will have to deal with you conflict.

Comment: Yes, but this is not a one time event.  Dealing with 100's or 1000's of conflicts each time we wish to push up another "release" to the github repo is not desirable.  I guess we'll have to go back to deleting all files in Beta, copying over the files from Alpha and doing a commit.  Was just hoping for a better way to utilize git's power.

Comment: IF I were you and you need to delete all files and copy over all files maybe just write it into a script that checks out the code from repo a, deletes all files in repo b, then copies over all of repo a and then commits to git for you. This way you don't need to do any manual work when changing and it becomes an easy small task.

Comment: If there is a divergence between both repository, there is developers on both repository, i understand the conflicts and there is no magic, you will have to resolve them. But if the repository is just for the release, for example : if it is for the client, I can guess that maybe you don't want to show the history of the git repository. but at one point, there is no merge to do, you can force to commit only your code. But I don't know exactly your workflow and the context.

Comment: Djory, you are correct we would have to deal with the conflicts if we had developers on both repos, but currently we do not.  So the problem remains, why are there conflicts and how can we automatically prefer the code in from Repo A to override the code in Repo B.  To clarify our workflow, we develop in Repo A exclusively.  At some point we wish to share that code to the world in Repo B.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is create the repo Alpha. Then anyone who wants to make changes needs to fork the repo. When they want to merge in their changes they then just need to do a pull request to alpha from their fork(beta repo).

https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/

https://help.github.com/articles/about-pull-requests/

Comment: Alpha already exists.  We use it daily, branching, committing, merging, etc.  We are comfortable with it and it is working well.  The problem is "How do we push the current state to a second repo (beta) without running into the conflicts described?"  But I feel like I'm misunderstanding your comment.  Are you saying that we need to fork "beta" and do pull requests?

Comment: You need to Fork alpha, What this does is it creates a clone of the original repo attached to that persons github account. They can then make their own branches and such and when they have something to contribute to the main repo you can do a pull request. Which merges their branch from their repo into your branch from the original repo. @Todd

Comment: Alpha is the gitlab repo and beta is the github repo.  I understand the concept of forking, but fail to see how that helps me push changes that we have been making in Alpha to Beta.  I will update the question with a diagram.

Comment: That's my mistake I misread that the original repo was a gitlab repo.